# Is there a way to detect directive destruction in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use a $timeout in a directive in AngularJS. But I can't find a way in the directive documentation to detect when it is destroyed, in case it happens before my timeout finishes and I need to cleanup the timeout.

Is there an event I can bind to or some built in function (similar to $destroy for controllers) that I can use to detect when my directive will be destroyed? Or am I missing a fundamental concept about directives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$destroy` event you mentioned can also be used in a directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        // Clean up
      });
    }
  };     
});
```

Comment: It's important to notice that the `$destroy` event is related to the scope, not to a controller or a directive.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about directive scope.

Comment: @Blackhole I tried to come up with a way that `$destroy` can be triggered with the directive still in the page, or that the directive can be removed from the page without `$destroy` having been triggered. Barring manually tinkering with the DOM, I couldn't think of one.

Comment: You're right about that. It was just a comment to help the OP understand what's going on in your code sample ;) .

Comment: Mind you that, if neither your directive nor another directive on the same element requests a new scope (isolated or not), the scope in question will belong to an ancestor of the element, meaning the directive itself might be destroyed and the scope lives on, never notifying your directive about it.

Comment: @diegovilar Can you give a concrete example, with code, where that happens?

Comment: As others mentioned, using scope for this purpose is not reliable. I think the better approach is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30778325/1056679.